# Jquery/Javascript sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading the following jquery, sometimes it works as expected however sometimes it doesn't, and i don't understand why?

When it does work i get no errors in firebug, however the times that it doesn't work i get an error **TypeError: b.pageZoom is undefined**

```
$this->template->jscripts = array (
            'assets/libraries/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js',
            'assets/libraries/jquery.validate.min.js',
            'assets/scripts/turn.min.js',
            'assets/scripts/turn.html4.min.js',
            'assets/libraries/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js',
            'assets/scripts/scripts.js?v=1.0'
        );
```

**My code from scripts.js?v=1.0**

```
function loadApp() {

// Create the flipbook
$('.flipbook').each(function(){
$(this).turn({
        // Width

        width:922,

        // Height

        height:600,

        // Elevation

        elevation: 50,

        // Enable gradients

        gradients: true,

        // Auto center this flipbook

        autoCenter: true
        });
}); 
  }
// Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform  
$(document).ready(function() {
yepnope({
test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
yep: ['../../lib/turn.js'],
nope: ['../../lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
both: ['css/basic.css'],
complete: loadApp
});
});
```

Comment: Dig a little deeper. A meaningless piece of code with the description "doesn't work" is not enough to help us help you.

Comment: You will need to comment out one of your Js n try running your code. If it works thats the culprit else try commenting out the next and so on. Thats hard but the only way.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with turn.js or your use of it (zoom is one of the methods on the API)

Comment: Must be a problem with asynchronous loading... please show more of your code.